# Two datepicker in one declaration bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.6.4 in my asp.net mvc application.

This is my code to show the date:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$input = $("#datepicker");

$input.datepicker({
    format: 'dd MM yyyy'
});
$input.data('datepicker').hide = function () { };
$input.datepicker('show');
```

As I want to show full datepicker selection but in output it is showing me two datepickers.

**OUTOUT:**

[image]

Don't have any solution anywhere I have searched a lot and this behavior is also awkward don't know but this should ideally not happen but in my case, it is happening.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your full code, why u doing hide and show?